# What in my code can be indentified as virus?

Tags: java

When I finish to do my home task, I get error "could not find or load main class".
I spent near 20 minutes in fully disunderstanding. Reason was "Kaspersky Anti-Virus", which was blocking my MyClass.class.
Here is the code, anyone knows, what's here Kaspersky can indentified as virus?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;

public class CryptoUtil extends JFrame{
    private String keyWord;
    private JFileChooser inputFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    private JButton openFileChooser = new JButton("Выбрать файл");
    private JTextField inputKeyWord = new JTextField();
    private JButton operate = new JButton("Выполнить");
    private File inputFile;
    private File encode;
    private File decode;
    private String inputData;


public CryptoUtil(){
    initFrame();
}

public void initFrame(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Шифратор/дешифратор XOR");
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    this.setSize(300, 100);
    operate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                operate();
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(encode.getParent()));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    openFileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            inputFileChooser.showOpenDialog(CryptoUtil.this);
        }
    });
    this.add(openFileChooser);
    this.add(inputKeyWord);
    this.add(operate);
}

public void operate() throws IOException {
    keyWord = inputKeyWord.getText();
    inputFile = inputFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    encode = new File(inputFile.getParent() + "//encode.txt");
    decode = new File(inputFile.getParent() + "//decode.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    inputData = sb.toString();
    br.close();
    PrintWriter writerEn = new PrintWriter(encode, "UTF-8");
    writerEn.print(encrypt(inputData, keyWord));
    writerEn.close();
    PrintWriter writerDe = new PrintWriter(decode, "UTF-8");
    writerDe.print(decrypt(encrypt(inputData, keyWord), keyWord));
    writerDe.close();
}


public byte[] encrypt(String text, String keyWord){
    byte[] arr = text.getBytes();
    byte[] keyArr = keyWord.getBytes();
    byte[] result = new byte[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        result[i] = (byte) (arr[i] ^ keyArr[i % keyArr.length]);
    }
    return result;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] text, String keyWord){
    byte[] result  = new byte[text.length];
    byte[] keyArr = keyWord.getBytes();
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length;i++){
        result[i] = (byte) (text[i] ^ keyArr[i% keyArr.length]);
    }
    return new String(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CryptoUtil().setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your Java executable (`java.exe`) is infected?

Comment: Or that your kaspersky just doesn't want java to be run ?

Comment: Antiviruses often consider executable files of unknown origin to be dangerous.

Comment: But another programs compiling and executing nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your file as trusted in kaspersky antivirus, same happened with me also, necessarily it won't be a virus.

Comment: It might be regarded as "suspicious behavior" when one program (e.g. javac.exe) creates other executable files. Many years ago, my Delphi compiler was involved in this kind of problem (when writing out .exe files) with the A/V. I don't think this is likely to happen for .class files too, but you never know.